# electrum - how to rename automatic a new wallet?

Tags: electrum

I am looking for a possibility to rename automatically new wallets.

my problem is that when I restore a wallet by terminal I get this error: "Remove the existing wallet first!"

But if I rename the default_wallet to wallet1 (for example) i get no error.

so is there a possibility to rename new wallets automatically to wallet1, wallet2, wallet3, ... ? maybe by electrum config?

Comment: Do you need something automatic, or would a way to move the wallets from the command line be sufficient?

Comment: automatically would be perfect but I am grateful for each solution

Comment: @Mr Jones i know that but if i restore the next two wallets i get the same error as before. thats why I am looking for a possibility to give each wallet their own names like wallet1, wallet2, wallet3,... I do not want to constantly edit the config file by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Change the source code.

Here you can see where the word 'default_wallet' is defined:
https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=default_wallet

If you would change that to 'wallet1' the default created wallet would be called wallet1.